# A word for "characterized by a defined ending"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am documenting some code and I need a word (adjective, preferably ending with "y") that means "characterized by a defined ending."

Here is how I will be using it in a sentence: "Unlike active scripts, passive scripts are capable of being started and stopped multiple times due to the simplicity, brevity, and [word I'm looking for] of their tasks."

I asked my friend and he suggested the word precursory, but I find that the meaning of that word is a bit too far from what I'm looking for.

Comment: *precursory* has a different sense and purpose.

Comment: Do you mean they are characterized by a definite outcome, or a certainty of their termination? Defined ending in/of what?

Comment: You asked for an adjective but it should be a noun instead of an adjective in your example sentence.

Comment: @Kris What I mean is that the task has a defined point, state, or condition which marks the completion of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **[terminability](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminability)**

> the quality or state of being terminable*
>
> <sub>[*terminable:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminable) able to be ended, capable of being terminated</sub>

---

**[finitude](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/finitude)** might fit also

> The quality or condition of being finite.

Comment: I really like terminability.

Answer (score 2):

Deterministic/Pre-determined/Pre-ordained- All seem to fit your bill.

Answer (score 1):

***predictability*** seems to have that connotation that the outcome is defined.

Maybe consider *specificity*, *regularity*, *consistency*, *particularity*, *reliability*?